# Getting DatePicker value in JavaFx to MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, javafx

I have a simple program to search holiday trips.
User is picking specific date when he want to travel and all viable travels should show in listbox.
If I press "Szukaj" button all trips should show in listBox on the right but nothing show up

[Main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ov9.png)

Here are my tables:
  infokraje(ID, IDK, odTermin, doTermin, iloscMiejsc)
  kraj(IDK, Kraj, Miasto)

That is database connection code:

```
   public ResultSet getTravel (infoKraje infoKraje) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    ResultSet resultSet;
    String query = "SELECT kraj.Kraj FROM kraj INNER JOIN infokraje ON infokraje.idK = kraj.idK WHERE infokraje.odTermin =" + "?";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setDate(1, infoKraje.getOdTermin());

    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    return resultSet;
}
```

And here is controller code:

```
    connectionDB = new ConnectionDB();
    travelList.setItems(cities);
    LocalDate odLDate = odPicker.getValue();
    Date odDate = Date.valueOf(odLDate);

    infoKraje infoKraje = new infoKraje();
    infoKraje.setOdTermin(odDate);

    ResultSet rs = connectionDB.getTravel(infoKraje);

    while(rs.next())
    {
        cities.add(rs.getString("Kraj"));
    }
```

travelList is my listBox, odPicker is my DatePicker and infoKraje is my JavaBean class.

Where is the error in code ?

Comment: Firstly, you need to provide a [mcve]. Secondly, we don't have magic powers - saying "nothing shows up" is too vague to tell us what has happened. You should really debug your code line by line to find out which part of your codes work, and which part doesn't.

Comment: I find out that there is some problem while converting LocalDate to Date. SQL doesn't see it when I put that into WHERE clause